# Rspec Validation Tests on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec

Good Evening fellow coders,

I'm slowly trying to get with grips Rspec and most of my validation occurs after the user is created as you can see from the validation below, here is the entire validation section so far.

```
 #validations for common attributes

 validates :email, presence: true, on: :create, uniqueness: true,
           :format => /@/
 validates :password, presence: true, on: :create, length: {minimum: 6}

 #validations blocks for dev

with_options :if => lambda { |o| o.role_type == "developer" } do |dev|
  dev.validates :first_name, presence: true, on: :update
  dev.validates :last_name, presence: true, on: :update
  dev.validates :languages, presence: true, on: :update
  dev.validates :dev_desc, presence: true, on: :update
  dev.validates :github, presence: true, on: :update, 
                :format => URI::regexp(%w(http https github))
  dev.validates :stackoverflow, presence: true, on: :update, 
                :format => URI::regexp(%w(http https stackoverflow))
  dev.validates :level, presence: true, on: :update
   dev.validates :street, presence: true, on: :update
   dev.validates :city, presence: true, on: :update
   dev.validates :state, presence: true, on: :update
   dev.validates :postcode, presence: true, on: :update
end

#validations block for employer

with_options :if => lambda { |o| o.role_type == "employer" } do |e|
    e.validates :company_name, presence: true, on: :update,
                uniqueness: true
    e.validates :employer_desc, presence: true, on: :update
    e.validates :area_of_focus, presence: true, on: :update
    e.validates :number_of_employees, presence: true, on: :update
 e.validates :street, presence: true, on: :update
 e.validates :city, presence: true, on: :update
 e.validates :state, presence: true, on: :update
 e.validates :postcode, presence: true, on: :update
end
```

Now I have my current test which is failing below:

```
    it "should not be valid with blank firstname" do
        dev.first_name = ' '
        dev.should_not be_valid
    end
```

The user is redirected to the edit page if they are not fully valid. I cannot understand why it isn't passing. I twisted it round and changed it to *should* which passed the test.

Could someone maybe explain why it's passing, here is the block for dev:

```
let(:dev) { FactoryGirl.create :dev }
```

**Update:** Here is my factory, not sure how this would effect the error:

```
factory :dev, class: User do
    first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
    last_name  { Faker::Name.last_name }
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    password "12345678"
    password_confirmation "12345678"
    role_type "Developer"
    dev_desc "New to development but trying to help the community"
    github "www.github.com"
    stackoverflow "www.stackoverflow.com"
    languages "Rails"
    level     "Junior"
    street    {Faker::Address.street_address}
    city      {Faker::Address.city}
    state    {Faker::Address.state}
    postcode {Faker::Address.zip_code}
end
```

Appreciate your help trying to understand this as validation works manually after sign up.

Comment: I still don't see what error you are getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validations for `first_name` are conditional on `role` being `"developer"`, but your factory sets `role` to be `"Developer"`, so the validations are not being applied.

Answer (score 0):

Change your validation to

```
dev.validates :first_name, presence: true, allow_blank: => false,  on: :update
```

By default, presence validation allows empty values

Comment: It still fails on my test.